# An authentication problem occurs in the Android web socket

Tags: java, websocket

I try to connect to the server using a web socket, but this error occurs.

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Here's my code for the connection.

```
private final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
        webSocket.send("text");

    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
        output("Receiving : " + text);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
        output("Receiving bytes : " + bytes.hex());
    }
    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
        output("Closing : " + code + " / " + reason);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
        output("Error : " + t.getMessage());
    }
}

private void start() {

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("wss://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443/one2many").build();
    EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
    WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
    client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
}

}
```

I am staying in this problem and I want you to help me!

Comment: The exception message implies that the server is using a certificate that the client doesn't trust.  For example, it could be a self-signed cert.  Does that give you some clues?